# Error when declare array struct in header file c++

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

**Header file:**

```
class SourceManager{

    typedef   struct  {
        const char  *name;
        int size ;
        const char  *src;
    }imgSources;

public:
    imgSources *   img;

    SourceManager();

};
```

**In cpp file:**

```
SourceManager::SourceManager(){

    img ={
       {  "cc",
            4,
            "aa"
        }
    };   
}
```

**It shows the error:** 
    - Cannot initialize a value of type 'imgSources *' with an lvalue of type 'const char [3]'
    -Too many braces around scalar initializer

How to fix it?

Comment: Interesting use of whitespace.

Comment: @tuan nguyen See at last my answer.:)

Comment: thank @VladfromMoscow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data member `img` is declared as having type of a pointer

```
imgSources *   img;
```

So in the constructor you need something like

```
SourceManager::SourceManager()
{

    img = new imgSources { "cc", 4, "aa" };
    //...
}
```

If you need to allocate an array of the structure then the constructor can look like

```
SourceManager::SourceManager()
{

    img = new imgSources[5] { { "cc", 4, "aa" }, /* other initializers */ };
    //...
}
```